# How can i add a red error box when no input text with js?

Tags: javascript

Right now i have just an alert, but i want to add an red error like "required" in js.

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById("aa").value == "") {
        alert("Fields should not be empty.");
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your HTML look, maybe create a fiddle to better explain what you want, https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Also what do you want to add the required to the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8540433/)

```
<input id='firstname' type="text" value='' />
<button onclick="validate()">Click me</button>

function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById("firstname").value == "") {
         alert("Fields should not be empty.");
         document.getElementById('firstname').className += ' required' 
    }
}

.required {
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: it's a pleasure, Please mark as answer if it works for you :-)